# Why is this type not a type in Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

I think I am invoking this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Boolean_

The build error is:
*'Gorp' is a type, which is not valid in the given context*

The Program class is

[image]

The Gorp class and Program class are as follows:

```
namespace foopy {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Object myObject;
            myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Gorp, true);
        }
    }
}

namespace foopy
{
    class Gorp
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof(Gorp) `. Also please don't post code as image.

Comment: @orhtej2 it's obvious to me that the image is posted to depict the structure of the project and to depict the location of the error.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Activator.CreateInstance` here? If you know the type at compile-time, just do `new Gorp(true)`.

Comment: @nicomp Not everyone can see images -- some people are behind firewalls which block imgur, others are on mobile devices which make it hard, or use screenreaders, or are hard-of-seeing and have the font size turned up. Images make life difficult for all of those people. They also mean that someone can't copy-paste the code then tweak it for their answer. You're welcome to post an image, but please *also* post any code as text.

Comment: @canton7 I reduced the problem to the smallest reproducible example.

Comment: @nicomp That's great, but please *post it as text*. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: That is a nice minimal repro. But, as everyone says, it's *much* better if you post it as text. @tanveerbadar's answer is correct. You should accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `Type` object, by using `typeof(Grop)`.